# Apache configuration to access directory

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, virtual-host

I'm on Ubuntu 9.10. My web application is in a directory on my `/home/me/app` . I want to configure Apache in such a way that I can access my app through a directory. For example:

People can access my machine through `domain.com`. What I would like to do is access my web application (located at `/home/me/app`) through a directory, using something like: `domain.com/myapp`.

How can I set up the Apache configuration for this kind of behavior?
Of course, I do not want to move all my application to `/var/www/myapp`.

The Alias directive did not solve my problem. If try to enter something like `mydomain.com/recommender/somedir`. It won't find anything. Because the alias only covers the `/recommender` path

What I would like, is something like a VirtualHost, but instead of pointing to a ServerName, I want to point it to a directory name.

Comment: See this page for more details about Alias:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html#Alias

For me, adding the Alias line was enough to allow access to subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could do it:

1. Create a symbolic link to /home/me/app in /var/www

   ln -s /home/me/app /var/www/myapp
2. Use the `Alias` directive in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

   Alias /myapp /home/me/app